# Deezer native API under linux: Unanble to create simple app

Tags: c++, linux, deezer

I tried to create simple app which will connect to deezer and play single song. I got access token and wrote this program.
Target machine: linux x86_64
API version: v1.0.1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deezer-api.h>
#include <deezer-player.h>

#define ACCESS_TOKEN "ACCESS TOKEN HERE"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    dz_connect_configuration cfg = {0};
    cfg.app_id = "APP ID HERE";
    cfg.product_id = "product_id";
    cfg.product_build_id = "0.0.0";

    dz_connect_handle dz_handle = dz_connect_new(&cfg);
    if (dz_handle == nullptr)
    {
        return 100;
    }

    auto err_code = dz_connect_activate(dz_handle, nullptr);
    if (err_code > DZ_ERROR_NO_ERROR_ASYNC)
    {
        return err_code;
    }

    err_code = dz_connect_set_access_token(dz_handle, nullptr, nullptr, ACCESS_TOKEN);
    if (err_code > DZ_ERROR_NO_ERROR_ASYNC)
    {
        return err_code;
    }

    auto dz_player_handle = dz_player_new(dz_handle);
    if (dz_player_handle == nullptr)
    {
        return 200;
    }

    err_code = dz_player_activate(dz_player_handle, nullptr);
    if (err_code > DZ_ERROR_NO_ERROR_ASYNC)
    {
        return err_code;
    }

    err_code = dz_player_load(dz_player_handle, nullptr, nullptr, "dzmedia:///track/3135556");
    if (err_code > DZ_ERROR_NO_ERROR_ASYNC)
    {
        return err_code;
    }

    err_code = dz_player_play(dz_player_handle, nullptr, nullptr, DZ_PLAYER_PLAY_CMD_START_TRACKLIST, DZ_TRACKLIST_AUTOPLAY_MANUAL, DZ_INDEX_IN_PLAYLIST_CURRENT);
    if (err_code > DZ_ERROR_NO_ERROR_ASYNC)
    {
        return err_code;
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Suddenly i ran into problems.
First run shows me this output:

> 398748:201417 dz_bufferevent: [dz_bufferevent_on_activation:561] could not open /var/tmp/settings.dat

I created this file, but I suspect that it shouldn't be empty.
After second run with /var/tmp/settings.dat created i got this output:

> 399206:328658 dz_crash_handler: [dz_crash_handler_init:284] Crash Handler available
>   399206:329404 dzcrashreport-server-disk: [dz_crashreport_server_url_on_read_data:436] ERROR - Open failure err: 7
>   399206:329533 dzcrashreport-server-disk: [dz_crashreport_server_url_on_read_data:436] ERROR - Open failure err: 7
>   399206:329590 dzcrashreport-server-disk: [dz_crashreport_server_url_on_read_data:436] ERROR - Open failure err: 7
>   399206:329664 dzcrashreport-server-disk: [dz_crashreport_server_url_on_read_data:436] ERROR - Open failure err: 7
>   399206:329726 dzcrashreport-server-disk: [dz_crashreport_server_url_on_read_data:436] ERROR - Open failure err: 7
>   399206:329736 dzcrashreport-sender: [dz_crash_report_sender_retrieve_server_url_on_result:213] Error - couldn't read URL server err:0
>   399206:336505 pulseaudio-engine: [dz_audioengine_set_output_gain:1184] not init
>   399206:336520 pulseaudio-engine: [dz_audioengine_set_output_gain:1184] not init
>   399206:336577 player: [dz_player_play_licence:1756] unknown error 131079

I can't understand, what i did wrong?

**UPDATE:**
Deezer Native API: v1.0.1-v00349200

Still no luck. Tried different variations of `"user_profile_path"`:

- .
- ./
- ./user - was created in working dir with 777 rights
- /var/tmp

There were no files in the folder created by API.

Still got errors:

> [dz_crashreport_server_url_on_read_data:436] ERROR - Open failure err: 7
>   [dz_crash_report_sender_retrieve_server_url_on_result:213] Error - couldn't read URL server err:0

After adding implementation of callbacks i see this:

1. `dz_connect_set_access_token` calls callback `dz_activity_operation_callback` with status `DZ_ERROR_CONNECT_SESSION_OFFLINE_MODE`
2. `dz_player_play` calls callback `dz_player_onevent_cb` with event `DZ_PLAYER_EVENT_PLAYLIST_TRACK_NO_RIGHT`

Well, i checked that i have rights to play this track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `"could not open"` message is just informative.
The file will be automatically created (or updated if detected corrupted).
The issue seems more linked to the dz_connect_configuration, you have to set the `"user_profile_path"` to a valid path. This is where user temporary files will be stored.
Regards,
Cyril

**UPDATE:**

Few tips that could also help:

- My mistake, one call seems missing:
  `dz_connect_cache_path_set(dz_handle, NULL, NULL, <user_profile_path>);`
- The `DZ_INDEX_IN_PLAYLIST_CURRENT` must be replaced by `0`. I do agree this one is not obvious...
- Check that the access_token you have created has the ***offline_access*** enable when calling `https://connect.deezer.com/oauth/auth.php?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&perms=basic_access,email,offline_access` (cf: http://developers.deezer.com/api/oauth and http://developers.deezer.com/api/permissions)

**UPDATE 2**:
Since my last answer I have released a sample code on Github:
https://github.com/deezer/native-sdk-samples

I suggest that you have a quick look :)

What I have noticed in your full code you sent me in private is that:

- You are not calling `dz_connect_offline_mode(...,false);` It will actually trigger the login process of the Native SDK.
- You are not waiting the `DZ_CONNECT_EVENT_USER_LOGIN_OK` to load and play the track.

Best regards,

Cyril

Comment: Thanks for response, @CyrilP.
About settings.dat: app doesn't create/update this file. With root access same problem.
Setting `"user_profile_path"` to `./` or `/var/tmp/` doesn't change anything, i got the same problem.

Comment: The three new points should really help. Do you confirm that you already have tried all of them together? If you confirm I suggest you send an email to deezerdevs@deezer.com with your access_token.
Regards,
Cyril

Comment: Hi @CyrilP! Yes, i did it, but still no luck. I got same errors.